# Change CDC ACM serial driver information

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver

I'm using a USB CDC serial converter. When I connect it to my computer it displays "USB-CDC Serial<>USB". Now I want to change this information to the name of my product. Does anybody know how to do it in Linux and Windows?

I want to change these information in dmesg:

```
[100480.031359] usb 2-1.8: Product: USB-CDC Serial<>USB
[100480.031362] usb 2-1.8: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[100480.031364] usb 2-1.8: SerialNumber: 1234
```

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a field in the USB device descriptor called iProduct at offset 15. This is called the product string descriptor.

You will need to change the firmware of the USB device and have it send the name of your product in this location.

Check out this website for more details on USB descriptors
http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to do change the device firmware?

Comment: Its different for every device. Check the manufacturer website.  http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/usbtouart/Pages/usb-to-uart-bridge.aspx